# How to make a single button loop through multiple sound files, one at a time, in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

First of all, I am a super xcode and objective-C noob. I have taken 2 college level Java classes, so I have an idea of what I want to do, I just can't accomplish it in xcode!

What I need to make happen is this: Push button1, play sound1. Push button1, play sound2. Push button1, play sound3. Push button1, play sound1. Et cetera.

What I am thinking is making a counter by saying
 i=0
 play sound
 i++
 then once i=4, make i=0 again and so on.

My sound player looks like this:

```
- (void) playSound:(NSString*) filename {

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat: filename, [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error: &error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

[audioPlayer play];

}
```

Any idea will be greatly appreciated! Don't be afraid to make it extremely simple, like I said I am really unexperienced

Comment: What problems are you having with your existing code?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are calling playsound method.. you are passing a filename.

so before calling the method update i(or any variable you have as count) .

and then make a switch statements and call the appropriate filename for the variable value....OR you can name the files like filename1,filename2,filename3 and just pass the the filename with i in the method and skip the switch.

Comment: Great, thanks! So in objective-C, what would the syntax be for declaring an integer, i, and making it go up once for a button push?

Comment: 1)make `i` a member variable. 2)in your view did load...put i =0;3)then make your button in the xib file and make it an IBAction.4) in your IBAction method increment i and then send your playSound method... I have divided this into 4 steps.. you can google each steps easily..